# What is the purpose of capistrano's "application" variable?

Tags: capistrano

Consider a Capistrano's config file with:

```
set :application, 'MyLittleApplication'
```

What is the purpose (or intent) of this variable? Or how is this variable used internally by Capistrano?

Both of these docs indicate you *can* use it for setting path. I feel like I'm missing something.
http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/
http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/preparing-your-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the github repo, the ***application*** variable seems to only be used for setting the default ***deploy_to*** variable. It doesn't really need to be set.

References:

- https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/docs/documentation/getting-started/configuration/index.markdown
- https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/defaults.rb